# NestJS access response object in pipes

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I am using pipes for request validation. If the request fails, I want to redirect to a page but don't want to throw error. The question is, how can I access the response object in validation?

This is my validation pipe.

```
@Injectable()
export class ValidationPipe implements PipeTransform<any> {
  async transform(value: any, { metatype }: ArgumentMetadata) {
    if (!metatype || !this.toValidate(metatype)) {
      return value;
    }
    const object = plainToClass(metatype, value);
    const errors = await validate(object);
    if (errors.length > 0) {
     // in here i need to response with res.redirect('') function
      throw new BadRequestException('Validation failed');
    }
    return value;
  }
  private toValidate(metatype: Function): boolean {
    const types: Function[] = [String, Boolean, Number, Array, Object];
    return !types.includes(metatype);
  }
}
```

Instead of throwing exception i need to access res.redirect() function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `response` object is not available from within the context of a `pipe`. What you could do is A) use an `interceptor` instead or B) throw an exception and use a `filter` to catch this specific exception and redirect to the correct location.

`Pipes` are only used for validation or object transformation and as such immediately return successes (with the possibly transformed object) or throw errors about why the transformation/validation failed.